# SQL and sum over each column from large table with window functions

Tags: sql, mysql, sum, multiple-columns, window-functions

In MySQL I have a table Stats with 100+ integers columns (eg. `points`, `small_points`), `player_id` (FK) and `date` column.

I want to calculate sum over 5 rows (starting from current row) for every single integer column, partitioned by `player_id` and ordered by `date`.

For column `points` I have such a query:

```sql
SELECT player_id, date AS start, 
sum(points) OVER (PARTITION BY player_id ORDER BY date ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND 5 FOLLOWING) AS total_points
FROM stats;
```

This example work pretty fast, but when I add more columns with `sum() over()`, execution time is drastically increasing. How to avoid such a situation? I guess all of the sorts are being executed for each column, but in fact they are the same.

I added more columns and performance decreased.

Comment: Please provide `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` and `EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON SELECT`...` for the query with 2 columns being summed.  And an abbreviated `SHOW CREATE TABLE ` only 2 of the columns, plus indexes.

Comment: Test separate, not inline, frame specification: `.. sum(points) OVER win .. WINDOW win AS (PARTITION BY ..) ..`.

Comment: Note that your window is 6 rows, not 5 as you say.

Comment: Does stats have a pk?  Is (player__id, date) unique?

Comment: In reference to Akina's suggestion - [Window Function Optimization](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-optimization.html#:~:text=The%20optimizer%20makes%20no%20attempt%20to%20merge%20windows%20that%20could%20be%20evaluated%20in%20a%20single%20step) - [Named Windows](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions-named-windows.html)